# Crash in dismissViewControllerAnimated (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c

Around 1% of my users are experiencing crashes when a view controller is being dismissed. I can't reproduce it myself, but Crashlytics is giving me stacktraces of the crashing code. From the stats it looks like the issue is not related to a certain OS version or a certain device type.

Here are the relevant code segments.

Somewhere in my `LoginViewController.m`, I have

```
if (someCondition) {
    PinViewController* pinViewController = [[PinViewController alloc] initWithSecret:secret target:self andLoginSuccessfulSelector:@selector(notifyAboutLoginAsync:)];
    [self presentViewController:pinViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
    [self performSelector:@selector(notifyAboutLoginAsync:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];
}
```

The `notifyAboutLoginAsync:` looks like this:

```
- (void)notifyAboutLoginAsync:(id)data {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; // crash happens on this line!
}
```

In the code above I am passing in the `notifyAboutLoginAsync:` selector to `PinViewController`'s `init` method, so that I can use it in `PinViewController`:

```
@property (readwrite) SEL loginSuccessfulSelector;
- (id)initWithSecret:(NSString *)pSecret target:(id)sTarget andLoginSuccessfulSelector:(SEL)successfulSelector {
    ...
    self.loginSuccessfulSelector = successfulSelector;
    ...
}
```

Then in `PinViewController` I also have

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    if (successful) {
        [[self target] performSelectorOnMainThread:[self loginSuccessfulSelector] withObject:[self pin] waitUntilDone:false];
    }
}
```

The crash happens in the `notifyAboutLoginAsync:` method.

My guess is that the LoginViewController might have already been dismissed when I call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:`, but I can't verify it because I can't reproduce it myself. Could my guess be the reason? If so, is there a way to check wether my controller has already been dismissed before calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated:`?

Attaching the crash trace at the end.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x5000000c
0    libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend + 5 isKindOfClass:
1    UIKit  -[UIWindow setDelegate:] + 122
2    UIKit  -[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState] + 700
3    UIKit  -[UIViewController _dismissViewControllerWithAnimationController:interactionController:completion:] + 618
4    UIKit  -[UIViewController _dismissViewControllerWithTransition:from:completion:] + 722
5    UIKit  -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerWithTransition:completion:] + 822
6    UIKit  -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerWithTransition:completion:] + 822
7    UIKit  -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:] + 222
```

Comment: my guess is your app is dismissing view controller(animated) while an animation is in progress.. present view controller(animated) i guess.. 

another is `- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated`, i guess it's much better to call your `performSelectorOnMainThread` inside `- (void)viewWillDisappear`.. i had an issue with something like this back then.. i don't really remember when.. it sound hard to debug this without reproducing it.. hmm.. anyway.. good luck to you.. :)

Comment: @0yeoj thank you :) To try your first guess, I will wrap my dismiss method in an `if (![self isBeingPresented] && ![self isBeingDismissed])` statement to see whether that can get the crash rate down a bit. For your second guess, is there a reason to move it into `viewWillDisappear`?

Comment: You're welcome... Let me know if my first guess resolved it.. (for additional knowledge, hihi..)

about my 2nd guess, i can't really recall what was it.. hmm.. as i recall i even tried moving my code before the `[super viewDidDisappear:animated];`, but didn't to any good.. anyway my second guess is not that usual so.. dont try it just now, try it after you tried the first one, since it much common when the app is in run time(on device)..

Comment: What version of iOS is this crash occurring on?

Comment: @Nikita it does not seem to be OS dependent: we are supporting only iOS 7 and above, and crash report shows that 88% of the crashes happen on iOS 8 and 11% happen on iOS 7